# FPDF error: The document is closed in

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, fpdf

I am generating pdf file using below code but it give me error in log file that

> FPDF error: The document is closed

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', 'Letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$filename=$upload_dir["basedir"].'/borrowers/borrower'.$page->id.'.pdf';
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'fdfd');
$pdf->Output('F',$filename);
```

However file is being generated in the destination path but script execution stopped further.

Comment: Did you try die(); after $pdf->Output('F',$filename);

Comment: Look if you have called 2 times Output function!
i have waste more time for th

Comment: This comment resolved the issue for me, so you didnt waste time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->state` value need to be increased in fpdf.php as by default it is 3 which seems to be low in case document contains more than 2 pages.

Comment: Your example code doesn't add more than a single page. This answer is wrong. I guess you'd not shown the whole code. Simply ensure that you do not call further methods on the object after calling Output().

Comment: @JanSlabon When I increased `$this->state` value it get fixed. So What issue caused it to stop working

Comment: I don't know the cause but your script is straight forward without anything special. There's no need to change any internal property. So the root cause is somewhere else. Did you checked your code for further interactions with the $pdf variable? Are you using the latest version of FPDF?

Answer (score 0):

My only solution to this was to use something else besides FPDF to generate PDFs. I'm running Laravel, generating PDFs in a queue. FPDF worked intermittently/randomly but was not consistent. I kept getting the "The document is closed in" error. I tried running the tasks outside a queue, tried increasing the queue memory, and a bunch of other things. I couldn't find the "$this->state" setting in the selected answer.

I ended up switching to this package:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

This issue may also be caused when generating multiple pages using a loop but referring to the outer instance of **Fpdi**. Take a look at the following rough guide:

```
//$pdf = new Fpdi();    //set outside loop for one-document-many-pages 

$mainCount = 2;
for($k=0; $k<$mainCount; $k++){
    //call fx to draw each page
    $pdf = new Fpdi();  //set inside loop for different documents
    //add a page for each loop
    $pdf->AddPage('P','A4');
    $pdf->setSourceFile($templateName);
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);  
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
    //....
}
```